# Understanding Double autoboxing

Tags: java, double, autoboxing

Consider the following example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double x1 = 0.0, y1 = -0.0;
    Double a1 = x1, b1 = y1;
    System.out.println(x1 == y1);       //1, true
    System.out.println(a1.equals(b1));  //2, false

    double x2 = 0.0, y2 = 0.0;
    Double a2 = x2, b2 = y2;
    System.out.println(x2 == y2);       //3, true
    System.out.println(a2.equals(b2));  //4, true

    double x3 = 0.0/0.0, y3 = 0.0/0.0;
    Double a3 = x3, b3 = y3;
    System.out.println(x3 != y3);       //5, true
    System.out.println(!a3.equals(b3)); //6, false
}
```

I tried to understand the autoboxing for `Double`, but could not. Why does the `//2` print `false`, but `//4` prints `true` whereas both `//1` and `//3` prints `true`. Why are they autoboxed in a different way?

Consulting the following [JLS 5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) section I realized that it's not specicified:

> If p is a value of type double, then:
>
> - If p is not NaN, boxing conversion converts p into a reference r of
>     class and type Double, such that r.doubleValue() evaluates to p
> - Otherwise, boxing conversion converts p into a reference r of class
>     and type Double such that r.isNaN() evaluates to true

So, are `//2`, `//4` and `//6` yeild in unspecified behavior and might end up in different results depending on the implementation?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals-java.lang.Object- has the answer to your exact question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All JAVA numeric types are signed unless specified differently

So,  0.0 is represented in binary as 0000000........0000000

-0.0 is represented as
10000000........0000000

Now, from what I understand, when you use equals() , the comparison is done in a bit-by-bit fashion from the 2 memory locations,  so it fails in your case.

**FROM THE java.lang.Double package**

`Double.equals(Double)` is implemented as follows

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (obj instanceof Double)
           && (doubleToLongBits(((Double)obj).value) ==
                  doubleToLongBits(value));
}
```

Comment: True for bit-by-bit, except that NaN values are *"collapsed to a single "canonical" NaN value"*. See javadoc of [`Double.equals(Object obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`Double.doubleToLongBits(double value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits%28double%29).

Comment: Added the internal implementation of the `Double.equals(Double)` method from the Java source package.

Comment: @Saibot Floating point uses sign-and-magnitude, not 2's complement. -0.0 has a 1 for the sign bit, and all the remaining bits 0.

Answer (score 5):

The Double equals method is documented in the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). The double == operation is documented in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1).

For most pairs of numbers they have the same result, but they are based on different conventions.

The double == is compatible with IEEE 754 arithmetic, in which a NaN is not equal to anything, not even itself, but 0.0 and -0.0 are equal.

Double is designed to have an equals method is compatible with its compareTo, reflecting a total order, and with its hashCode, so hash tables will work with Double keys. NaN is treated as equal to itself, and -0.0 is less than, rather than equal to, 0.0.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the Javadoc for `Double` closely, you will notice that negative and positive zero are not equivalent, at least under comparison using `equals()`:

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Note that in most cases, for two instances of class Double, d1 and d2, the value of d1.equals(d2) is true if and only if

```
d1.doubleValue() == d2.doubleValue()
```

> also has the value true. However, there are two exceptions:
>
> If d1 and d2 both represent Double.NaN, then the equals method returns true, even though Double.NaN==Double.NaN has the value false.
> **If d1 represents +0.0 while d2 represents -0.0, or vice versa, the equal test has the value false, even though +0.0==-0.0 has the value true.**

Comment: can you please explain in detail, how does the `+0.0==-0.0` become true?

Answer (score 2):

> ...for two instances of class Double, d1 and d2, the value of
>   d1.equals(d2) is true if and only if
>
> ```
> d1.doubleValue() == d2.doubleValue()
> ```
>
> also has the value true. However, there are two exceptions:
>
> If d1 and d2 both represent Double.NaN, then the equals method returns true, even though Double.NaN==Double.NaN has the value false.
>
> If d1 represents +0.0 while d2 represents -0.0, or vice versa, the equal test has the value false, even though +0.0==-0.0 has the value
>   true.
>
> This definition allows hash tables to operate properly.

Please refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

Answer (score 1):

Javadoc of [`Double.equals(Object obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Note that in most cases, for two instances of class `Double`, `d1` and `d2`, the value of `d1.equals(d2)` is `true` if and only if
>
> ```
> d1.doubleValue() == d2.doubleValue()
> ```
>
> also has the value `true`. However, there are two exceptions:
>
> - If `d1` and `d2` both represent `Double.NaN`, then the `equals` method returns `true`, even though `Double.NaN==Double.NaN` has the value `false`.
> - **If `d1` represents `+0.0` while `d2` represents `-0.0`, or vice versa, the `equal` test has the value `false`, even though `+0.0==-0.0` has the value `true`.**
>
> This definition allows hash tables to operate properly.